# StackNavigator in TabNavigator in StackNavigator, TabNavigator switches to wrong tab

Tags: javascript, react-native, navigation, react-navigation

I'm currently facing an issue where my TabNavigator which is nested inside a StackNavigator is not opening in the initialRouteName that I define.

It's easiest to see this with an example so here we go:

Outermost (StackNavigator)

```js
const RootStackNavigator = StackNavigator(
  {
    Main: {
      screen: MainTabNavigator,
    },
    Login: {
      screen: LoginScreen,
    },
    Splash: {
      screen: SplashScreen
    }
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Splash',
    headerMode: 'float',
  }
);

export default class RootNavigator extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this._notificationSubscription = this._registerForPushNotifications();
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this._notificationSubscription && this._notificationSubscription.remove();
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <RootStackNavigator />
    );
  }
}
```

MainTabNavigator (TabNavigator):

```js
const HomeStackNavigator = StackNavigator(
  {
    //Lots of screens.
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'HomeScreen',
    headerMode: 'none',
  }
);

const BStackNavigator = StackNavigator(
  {
    //Lots of screens.
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'BScreen',
    headerMode: 'none',
  }
);

const CNavigator = StackNavigator(
  {
    //Lots of screens
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'CScreen',
    headerMode: 'none',
  }
);

const DStackNavigator = StackNavigator(
  {
    //Lots of screens.
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'DScreen',
    headerMode: 'none',
  }
);

const EStackNavigator = StackNavigator(
  {
    //Lots of screens
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'EScreen',
    headerMode: 'none',
  }
);

export default TabNavigator(
  //Adds elements to the navigator at the bottom.
  {
    Home: {
      screen: HomeStackNavigator
    },
    B: {
      screen: BStackNavigator,
    },
    C: {
      screen: CStackNavigator,
    },
    D: {
      screen: DStackNavigator,
    },
    E: {
      screen: EStackNavigator,
    }
  },
  {
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => {
        const { routeName } = navigation.state;
        let iconName;
        switch (routeName) {
          //define icons.
        }
        return (
            <Ionicons
              name={iconName}
              size={24}
              style={{ marginBottom: -3 }}
              color={focused ? Colors.tabIconSelected : Colors.tabIconDefault}
            />
        );
      },
    }),
    tabBarOptions: {
      inactiveBackgroundColor: '#4d5a8b',
      activeBackgroundColor: '#4d5a8b',
      showLabel: false,
      initialRouteName: 'Home'
    },
    tabBarComponent: TabBarBottom,
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
    animationEnabled: false,
    swipeEnabled: false
  }
);
```

What I'm expecting is for the app to initially go to the splash screen. Check if the user is signed in, yes they are, then go to the MainTabNavigator's initialRouteName but what actually happens is that it's initially loads in the Home tab, and then after about 2-3 seconds it flicks over to the D tab.

Note: One thing I have noticed is that I have some screens in multiple of the StackNavigators for the tabs, for example you can navigate to ScreenX from the BStackNavigator and the CStackNavigator.

Has anyone experienced this before and have a way of getting around it?

I'd really appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because the `initialRouteName` parameter is at the wrong place.

**Example:**

```
export default TabNavigator(
  //Adds elements to the navigator at the bottom.
  {
    Home: {
      screen: HomeStackNavigator
    },
    B: {
      screen: BStackNavigator,
    },
    C: {
      screen: CStackNavigator,
    },
    D: {
      screen: DStackNavigator,
    },
    E: {
      screen: EStackNavigator,
    }
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home', // SHOULD BE HERE
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
     ...
    }),
    tabBarOptions: {
      inactiveBackgroundColor: '#4d5a8b',
      activeBackgroundColor: '#4d5a8b',
      showLabel: false,
      //initialRouteName: 'Home', SHOULD NOT BE HERE
    },
    tabBarComponent: TabBarBottom,
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
    animationEnabled: false,
    swipeEnabled: false
  }
);
```

**Doc:**

- [TabNavigator API](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/tab-navigator.html#tabnavigatorconfig)

Comment: I had already tried it outside of the tabBarOptions, but let me try again.

Comment: But anyhow, from the Docs, it looks to me like it should be within tabBarOptions anyway.

Comment: I agree the doc is a bit confusing

Comment: Well, the good news is that if I remove the tab it doesn't navigate there anymore, so it seems like it probably was just me being a nonce. Facepalm.